# How can I import or include xsl stylesheet from one xsl to another xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I import or include xsl stylesheet from one xsl to another xsl

This is my code

## Employee.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>  
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "employee.xsl"?>   
<class>   
   <employee id = "016">  
      <firstname>Aryan</firstname>   
      <lastname>Gupta</lastname>   
      <linkurl>https://www.aryanguptan.com/external</linkurl>   
      <salary>30000</salary>  
   </employee>   
        <employee id = "080">   
      <firstname>Sam</firstname>   
      <lastname>Alex</lastname>   
      <linkurl>/user/internal/080</linkurl>   
      <salary>10000</salary>   
   </employee>  
   <employee id = "024">   
      <firstname>Sara</firstname>   
      <lastname>Khan</lastname>   
      <linkurl>http://www.sarakhan.com</linkurl>   
      <salary>25000</salary>  
   </employee>   
    <employee id = "092">   
      <firstname>John</firstname>   
      <lastname>Samuel</lastname>   
      <linkurl>/user/internal/092</linkurl>   
      <salary>10000</salary>   
   </employee> 
   <employee id = "056">   
      <firstname>Peter</firstname>   
      <lastname>Symon</lastname>   
      <linkurl>www.petersymon.com</linkurl>   
      <salary>10000</salary>   
   </employee>    
</class>
```

This is the xsl sheet of this code

## Employee.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
 <xsl:import href="globaVar.xsl" />     
   <xsl:template match = "/">      
    <xsl:apply-imports/>   
      <html>   
         <body>   
            <h2>Employee </h2>   
            <table border = "1">   
               <tr bgcolor = "pink">   
                  <th>ID</th>   
                  <th>First Name</th>   
                  <th>Last Name</th>   
                  <th>Link URL</th>   
                  <th>Salary</th>   
               </tr>           
               <xsl:for-each select = "class/employee">                                 
                     <tr>   
                        <td><xsl:value-of select = "@id"/></td>   
                        <td><xsl:value-of select = "firstname"/></td>   
                        <td><xsl:value-of select = "lastname"/></td>  
                        <xsl:variable name="linkurl" select="linkurl" />
                        <xsl:choose> 
                            <xsl:when test="$lookup/tld[starts-with($linkurl, .)]">
                                <td><a href="{linkurl}" target="_blank"><xsl:value-of select = "linkurl"/></a></td>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <td><a href="www.google.com/{linkurl}"><xsl:value-of select = "concat('www.google.com/',linkurl)"/></a></td>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>                            
                        <td><xsl:value-of select = "salary"/></td>  
                     </tr>                        
               </xsl:for-each>         
            </table>   
         </body>   
      </html>  
   </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here I am trying to import this code(GlobalVar.xsl) some other xsl sheet for the reusabilty pupose

## GlobalVar.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template name="linkURLTemplate">
    <xsl:variable name="tlds">
          <tld>http://</tld>
          <tld>https://</tld>
          <tld>www.</tld>      
       </xsl:variable>         
       <xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name='tlds']"/>   
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But when I am trying to run employee.xml i am getting this error

"Error during XSLT transformation: An unknown error has occurred ()"

Can you helo what i did wrong?

Comment: Run the XSLT with a processor or an IDE that gives you are more detailed error message than your currently used tool (a browser?). In addition to the error displayed in the browser window, check the developer console with F12 or similar for more detailed info. If you expect the imported stylesheet to export a variable to the importing one then use a global variable, i.e. a top level `xsl:variable`. Furthermore named templates are not used by `apply-imports` and to use variables you don't need to apply any templates. Relying on `document('')` is a rather fragile approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors in your stylesheets:

1. You have the wrong name for your sub-stylesheet in `Employee.xsl`. So change the line

   ```
   <xsl:import href="globaVar.xsl" />
   ```

   to

   ```
   <xsl:import href="GlobalVar.xsl" />
   ```
2. In your sub-stylesheet `GlobalVar.xsl` you did not define the variables at the top-level, but rather in a template. But you have to define them at the top-level to use them in your other templates. So remove the `xsl:template` from `GlobalVar.xsl` to look like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

       <xsl:variable name="tlds">
           <tld>http://</tld>
           <tld>https://</tld>
           <tld>www.</tld>      
       </xsl:variable>    

       <xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:variable[@name='tlds']"/>   

   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```

   Here I also changed the definition of the `lookup` variable to

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:variable[@name='tlds']"/>
   ```

   to have a more direct access this variable.

Now your stylesheets should work as expected.

Comment: Correct. So the error was trying to use a variable without its declaration. Something like: `Stylesheet compilation failed with 1 error(s):
Error 1 at line 23:7 : Variable lookup has not been declared (or its declaration is not in scope)`